# Redirect not working in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have two models, one that is called Timelines and other called Contests.

```
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :timeline
end

class Timeline < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

While I am inside `http://localhost:3000/timelines/1` this path for instance I have a button that when I click it I want to make a redirection to create a new contest.

```
<button type="button" onclick="setContest(0)">Before</button>

function setContest(type){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/contests/new',
        type: 'GET',
        data:
        {
            "before": type,
            "timeline_id": $("#timeline_id").text(),
            "video_id": $("#video_id").text()
        }
    }).success(function(d){
        location.replace(d.new_path);
    }).fail(function(err){

        alert(err.value);
    });
}
```

But when I click it I got the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TimelinesController#show
Couldn't find Timeline with 'id'=undefined

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_timeline
      @timeline = Timeline.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
```

Any idea of what might be going on wrong and what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: Why don't you just use a normal html link?

Comment: Like @spickermann said, why not use a usual HTML link? Can you post the routes here, we can help you out with the link.

Comment: hum... to be honest I didn't even thought of that. Will give it a try.

@IleEftimov what routes do you want?

Comment: Just the output of `rake routes` would be sufficient.

Comment: @IleEftimov added to original post

Comment: I tried with href but it goes to: http://localhost:3000/timelines/undefined/contests/new?video_id=&timeline_id=&before=0 instead of http://localhost:3000/contests/new?video_id=&timeline_id=&before=0

Here is the code:

function setContest(type){
 var URL;
 var timeline_id=$("#timeline_id").text();
 var video_id= $("#video_id").text();
 URL+="/contests/new?video_id=" + video_id + '&timeline_id=' + timeline_id + '&before=' + type;
 return URL;
}

<a href="javascript:window.location=setContest(0);">Before</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views, add a link:

```
link_to "New contest", new_contest_path(video_id: params[:video_id], timeline_id: params[:timeline_id])
```

This will create a link with the ids as the query string.

HTH

Comment: I already tried it and it works without any problem. The thing is my video_id is stored in a <span></span> and I think I need to use javascript to get it I think :/

Comment: Well, if your `video_id` is stored in a span, a good question would be how does it get there (in the span) in the first place?

Comment: on page load for each video I create an input button. That input has an onclick="popup(video_id, video_name)" during the on click fuction a dialog will appear where the link to will be and in the popup function I store the video_id in a span 

 <input type="image" onclick="setPopup('<%= p.title %>', '<%= p.id %>')" style="width:50px;height:50px;" />
^

Probably I should posted that in the beginning also

Comment: I see a typo there, you use `params[:videoid]` instead of `params[:video_id]`, could that be the problem?

Comment: Forget about it. I did a thing which is not pretty, but it worked (I replicated the model for each video) so I will accept your answer and call it a day. Don't want to keep bothering with this xD